# How to use Yahoo Pipe to build a new feed based on a feed whose content is multi-paged?

Tags: rss, feed, yahoo-pipes

Currently, I  subscribe a feed. It's content has multi-pages, but the feed's item only points to the first page. So if I only subscribe this feed in google reader, I can only view the first pages's content.

So I think there might be some way to get the full content. But after I searched the web, I can't find any tutorial on what I'm looking for. So can anyone provide some information on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fetch the web page from the url in feed and get the additional pages and add to the content. I can provide you with tutorial but will need the url of feed you are aiming at.